# JavaScript and Google API Service Account Private Key formatting

Tags: javascript, encryption, jwt

I am struggling with authorisation to Google OAuth2.0 for Service Account.

The script I am writing is pure ECMASCript5, it is running on special purpose server and the communication will be my server - Google server.

I am following this documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

I have created my signed JWT as described in the documentation.

The problem I have is that after I send access token request, the response form Google server is :

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}

My suspicion is that I may have my private key formatted in wrong way. Google documentation seems to confirm that too.
The key is saved in JSON file downloaded from Google dev console / service account dashboard, and it is in following format:

"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEugIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKQwggSgAgEAAoIBAQDE5vuC4GeikWBu\n8ZQEkcJMFBHJAW40b2WogwWc46pSAnvPVtbeEoVI4n8qx3r2IfpURqQgRr............................=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

The questions is - should I format the key in some way before using it in my encryption method for JWT sign? I noticed it has lots of '\n' and some '=' characters. Should it have newlines or just one line? Should it have the headers?

I have tried `.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')` and even `.replace(/\\n/g, '')` but that does not seem to work either.

I am using server's dedicated library and it is closed system without possibility of importing external libraries.

One more confusing thing:
Google documentation says the JWT should be following format:

```
{Base64url encoded header}.
{Base64url encoded claim set}.
{Base64url encoded signature}
```

But then in error description they say:

> Alternatively, the JWT assertion might be encoded incorrectly - it
> must be Base64-encoded, without newlines or padding equal signs.

Is this a mistake when they say in the error description about base64 encoding as opposed to earlier base64url encoding?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're never sending the private key to Google or anywhere else that you don't control. Scanning through the documentation that you linked to, you're supposed to get the key pair including the private key from the API.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Correct. I am using the private key only to sign the JWT. But but the JWT is being rejected by google and hence my doubt regarding the key formatting when I use it as an input to signing method.